# SQL Server Driver for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, odbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server using SQLALchemy.

```
connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://testuserr:testuserr@BGBY/main?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
```

but my manager doesn't use Driver 17. is there any driver for work all Server?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Define the path to your CSV file
csv_file = #

# Define the connection string to your SQL Server database
connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://testuser:testuser@BGBY/main?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
# Create a SQLAlchemy engine to connect to the SQL Server database
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Transfer the DataFrame to the SQL Server database
df.to_sql('mytablenamee', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

that is my code

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: _is there any driver for work all Server?_ Nope. Each version of ODBC Driver for SQL Server only supports a subset of SQL Server versions. Ref: [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility). Since the current ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server works with all supported versions of SQL Server, though, you probably need to upgrade your old SQL Server to something modern, supported and patched.